# Sum of dice bet

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You have a 50 sided die and a 100 sided die. You bet on the sum of the dice and receive points equal to the sum of the dice. What is the sum that you choose to bet on to maximize your earnings.

I was able to do this for a 6 sided die and a 10 sided die.
My approach was to calculate the probability for 9,10,11 and 12 as the sum and found that P(9) = P(10) = P(11) = 1/10 > P(12) and hence I choose 11.

However I'm unable to calculate the same for large numbers like 50 and 100. Is there a way to calculate this easily? This is an interview question (both parts)

Comment: With a 6-die and a 10-die, you can see that we have 3 groups, Total from 2 to 7, from 7 to 11, and from 11 to 16. Values 7 and 11 are at the frontier, and can be consider in one or another group. All numbers from 7 to 11 have same probability. If we transpose to 50-die plus 100-die, 7 becomes 51, and 11 becomes 101.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for $101$. There are $50$ ways to make it, which is the maximum possible, and $102\cdot49=4998<5050=101\cdot50$.